# Scanf in multiple goroutines giving unexpected results

Tags: go

I was simply experimenting in golang. I came across an interesting result. This is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var str1, str2 string
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &str1)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    go func() {
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &str2)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", str1, str2)
}
```

I gave the following input.

```
beat
it
```

I was expecting the result to be either

```
it beat
```

or

```
beat it
```

But I got.

```
eat bit
```

Can any one please help me figure out why it is so?

Comment: If you do things in parallel, it may happen that they're really done in parallel. It's hard to see why you find the result surprising, which makes your question unclear.

Comment: But if I use `bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)` instead of `Scanf()` the results are as expected.

Comment: Interesting. Is it an interaction between stdio and Scanf?   Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Without having tried it, I bet if you write a test and run with -race, you'll unearth more problems than the one's you've seen so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fmt.Scanf` isn't an atomic operation. Here's the implementation  : http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/scan.go#L1115

There's no semaphor, nothing preventing two parallel executions. So what happens is simply that the executions are really parallel, and as there's no buffering, any byte reading is an IO operation and thus a perfect time for the go scheduler to change goroutine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why it happens only with one character?

Comment: Oh! Never mind. It happens with more than one characters. But only those in the beginning..

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are sharing a single resource (the stdin byte stream) across multiple goroutines.

Each goroutine could be spawn at different non-deterministic times. i.e:

1. first goroutine 1 read all stdin, then start goroutine 2
2. first goroutine 2 read all stdin, then start goroutine 1
3. first goroutine 1 block on read, then start goroutine 2 read one char and then restart goroutine 1
4. ... and so on and on ...

In most cases is enough to use only one goroutine to access a linear resource as a byte stream and attach a channel to it and then spawn multiple consumers that listen to that channel.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    words := make(chan string, 10)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for {
            var buff string
            _, err := fmt.Scanf("%s", &buff)
            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
                }
                break
            }
            words <- buff
        }
        close(words)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    // Multiple consumers
    for i := 0; i < 5; i += 1 {
        go func() {
            for word := range words {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", word)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```